# iTunes Connect app icon automatically changed

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted my app to app store.
This is my app update and 1.0 version of my app exists in app-store. While uploading 1.0 version in iTunes Connect i used 1024 x 1024 rectangle shaped app icon. After submitting in iTunes connect, app icon changed to round rectangle and in iTunes store the app icon looks in round rectangle shape.

Now after uploading new version of my app 1.1, it automatically invoked 1.0 app icon, screenshots and other meta data.
It invoked the round rectangle app icon also to 1.1 version and it was like that till yesterday. Now my new app version status is "Waiting for Review".

Suddenly now it changed to rectangle shaped instead of round rect automatically. 
Now for both versions 1.0 and 1.1 the app icon changed to rectangle shape. Why is this happened for both the versions?

Will it be changed to round rectangle again or do i have to modify it manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itunesconnect app icon has the rounded rectangle because it has CSS that changes your rectangle app icon on the fly when it is viewed in the browser. So I would say not to worry and leave your app icon in rectangle shape.

Sometimes the CSS to put the rounded corner is disabled, just like at this moment (I just inspected the element in the page). You can see below there is a div element with the class icon-mask. That is the one responsible for adding the rounded corner, but currently it is not displayed because it has the `style="display: none;"` added by Apple. Not sure why they disable the mask though.

[image: CSS that adds the mas]

The actual image file is still rectangle anyway. And you can also try to see the actual image by right-click and open image in new tab or something similar.

PS: for fun, here is the CSS of the class icon-mask:

```
.icon-mask {
    background: url('/itc/images/large-icon-mask.png') no-repeat;
    width: 170px;
    height: 173px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: My Actual image is rectangle shape. I wanted it to convert to rounded shape. I am worried whether it will change to rounded one.

Comment: @jithen It will. Try to check later in a few minutes time.

Comment: Thank you. I will check after sometime/

Comment: It will appear same as you have integrated.

Comment: Excellent Verbumdei... I found the style and it is set to "none" now. It will be changed to round rectangle later in sometime or do i have to upload new rectangle shape icon?

Comment: @jithen that one you need to ask Apple :). I believe it will be changed though to automatically add back the rounded corner. So I guess you do not need to upload a new icon.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have added same Icon file to both version. And it is the same icon which you have integrated with application. You also have same icon for iTunesartwork in application. May be you have some change in icon at some place. I assume that you have same Icon for both version.

Comment: I didnt change my app icon. My 1.0 app icon is invoked to 1.1 version. And i submitted my app on May 28th. Now the status is "Waiting for Review". Till yesterday my app icon was in round rectangle shape only. Now today suddenly it changed to rectangle shape. And the status of my app still is "Waiting for Review".

Comment: @jithen Sometimes the website fails to add the rounded corners.  In my experience, it corrected itself a while later.

Comment: Thanks Borden. Have you ever faced this kinda issue?

Comment: It will appear same as you have integrated

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this has to do with iOS 7 release.
It was rumored about new flat app icons.